# Qos while sending video over wireless networks

Tags: video

I want to improve QOS of video transmission over Wireless Networks.. 
Can anyone tell me a method for that? how can i show a simulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on the type of wireless network and whether you have control over the network or not - for example if it is a private or company wifi network that you can actually set policies on then you have more options then if it is simply a public 3G network.

It also depends on exactly what you mean by QoS - I am guessing you mean how 'good' the users experience is.

If you have no control over the network then the there are still a number of things you can do to help - none of them will deal with extreme situations like bad cell congestion or poor wireless reception, but in less extreme conditions they will help:

- Reduce the video size/quality - less to send means less need for bandwidth
- Increase the buffer size - takes longer to start but then has more 'in reserve' to deal with interruptions
- Use some form of adaptive bit rate streaming - this effectively changes the bit rate of the video depending on network conditions.

If it is a network you do have control over then you can use QoS mechanisms to give your video traffic priority over 'best effort' web browsing etc. It is worth designing this carefully to make sure that video is actually your highest priority - you may want voice or some audio services to have the same or higher priority.